# Why won't gcc compile a class declaration as a reference argument?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, reference, arguments

This compiles fine in Visual studio,  but why not in XCode?

```
class A()
{};

someMethod(A& a);

someMethod(A()); //error: no matching function call in XCode only :(
```

Is this bad form?
it seems annoying to have to write the following every time:

```
A a;
someMethod(a);  //successful compile on Xcode
```

Am i missing something?  I am not very experienced so thank you for any help!

Comment: All the pain caused by Microsoft-specific extensions ... its too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference.  It would work if you changed the function to take a const reference:

```
someMethod(const A& a);
```

In addition,

```
A a();
```

does not declare a local variable.  It declares a function named `a` that takes no parameters and returns an object of type `A`.  You mean:

```
A a;
```

Answer (score 0):

For passing references to rvalues (of which the reference is implicitly obtained) like it's done in `someMethod(A())`, you need *constant references*. The valid declaration (including correct syntax) therefore is

```
void someMethod(const A& a);
```