# Passing a non-reference as a reference, without temp variable

Tags: c++, gcc, reference

I am trying to do the following: call a function which takes references as parameters without passing "variables", just values.
Shouldn't my compiler(gcc) be able to make temporary "variables" to send in? It would seem that mvc does it, one way or another (other person in project uses it).

I have:

```
foo(Vector&,Vector&)
```

Whenever I try to call `foo(Vector(1,2,3),Vector(4,5,6))` I get `no matching function for call to foo(Vector,Vector); note: candidates are foo(Vector&,Vector&)`

What should I do?
Why doesn't it work? Is there some concept I do not comprehend?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a MSVC "extension" which is an incorrect nuisance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't gcc compile a class declaration as a reference argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530624/why-wont-gcc-compile-a-class-declaration-as-a-reference-argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Vector(1,2,3)` creates a temporary, and a temporary cannot be bound to **non-const** reference!

So make the parameters `const` as:

```
void foo(const Vector&, const Vector&)
```

Now it'll work!

Comment: @Downvoter: What is wrong with it? Please explain so I can know!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass as const reference:

```
foo(const Vector&,const Vector&)
```

non-const references can be bound only to l-values, temporary is not a l-value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `const` references if you want to pass over temporary variables.